# Accessing vitual linux-system

Tags: linux

I have just installed an virtual Linux system. I was trying to access is from a different location but I could get trough.
When I have looked up the ip-address (ifconfig) on the system, which is:

> inet addr: 10.0.2.15

but I still cant seem to manage it. Can anyone help?

Comment: Change your network settings from NAT to Bridged Adapter

Answer (score 0):

It depends on virtualizing software you're using, but address pretty much looks like NATed. In that case you can't directly access it, unless you'll configure VM to map virtual network controller directly to host network.

Comment: Depending on the VM software, you may be able to change the virtual network adapted to be bridged.

Comment: which VM sofware are you using? Means virtual box or VMware ?

Comment: I'm using Virtual box

Comment: http://catlingmindswipe.blogspot.ru/2012/06/how-to-virtualbox-networking-part-two.html 'bridged adapter' part. Ofc you'll have to assign different IP address to guest system.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean with different location? 10.x.x.x are private IP addresses, which can only be accessed within its subnet. What IP address does the host system have?

If the host system is within 192.168.x.x subnet, then an outside computer cannot know how to access 10.x.x.x when there is no route. You have then to set up NAT on your host computer.

A more easier approach would be to use bridged networking which will then eventually get an IP address through DHCP from your router (or whatever you might have).